# How to generate dynamic table on mpdf?

Tags: php, mpdf

I have to generate a table with given array which is dynamic. I want to have 3 `<td>`'s in each row. I thought adding new row when counter value is 3 but don't know to put second row values inside. How can I build the logic for that?

```
    public function mpdf_output($array)
{
    $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['format' => 'A4-L']);

    $counter = 0;

    $mpdf->WriteHTML('<table style="width:100%"><tr>');

        foreach($array as $barcode)
        {
            $mpdf->WriteHTML('<td><p style="float:left;">code</p>');
            $mpdf->WriteHTML('<barcode code="'.$barcode['code'].'" type="C128B" class="barcode" />');
            $mpdf->WriteHTML('<p>'.$barcode['img'].'</p></td>');
            $counter++;

            if($counter == 3)
            {
                $mpdf->WriteHTML('Counter restarted');
                $counter = 0;
            }
        }
    $mpdf->WriteHTML('</tr></table>');

    $mpdf->Output();
}
```

Comment: why don't you create your HTML(table) first and pass it to `WriteHTML` once

Comment: @ParitoshMahale still don't know how to set up the proper logic for that.

Answer (score 2):

As Paritosh commented, you'll need to pass the complete `<table>` markup to mPDFs `WriteHTML` method for it to process correctly. However, it looks like you just want to make use of a three-column layout in the PDF. If that's the case, I'd opt for the much simplier `float` solution:

```
$html = '';

foreach($array as $barcode)
{
    $html .= '<div style="float: left; width: 33%;">code<barcode code="'.$barcode['code'].'" type="C128B" class="barcode" />' . $barcode['img'] .'</div>');        
}

$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
```